# Kotlin: How to call getSupportFragmentManager() in RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to call the Support Fragment Manager in my RecyclerView.Adapter after the click event in order to move to a different fragment. My approach:

```
(context as MainActivity).supportFragmentManager
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(MainActivity.FRAGMENT_CONTAINER, TextScreen())
                            .commit()
```

But I get the following error:

> kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type

Can you help me?

Comment: `context` is null, just make sure to set a value before casting it to `MainActivity `

Comment: It is a `Typecast Exception` and it is saying `can not be cast to non-null type` something which does not allow null you are passing null to it. In Kotlin you need to add `?` to make in nullable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your `Context` instance in the adapter is not guaranteed to be an `Activity`. It could potentially be a `ContextWrapper` holding the `Activity` as a base `Context`. Attempting to unwrap this would be fragile.

Instead, I would recommend that you define an interface in your adapter. From your `Activity`, provide an implementation of this interface to your adapter that will perform the `FragmentTransaction`. For example:

```
class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyType> {
    private var listener: (() -> Unit)? = null

    fun setListener(listener: (() -> Unit)?) {
        this.listener = listener
    }

    // wherever your onClick is handled:
    listener?.invoke()
}
```

Then, in the `Activity` that's initializing `MyAdapter`:

```
myAdapter.setListener {
    supportFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(MainActivity.FRAGMENT_CONTAINER, TextScreen())
        .commit()
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Updated for 2021 - ***Kotlin Answer***

> If you want to call *"supportFragmentManager"* in **Fragment**

```
activity.supportFragmentManager
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you handle your fragment transaction in your `fragment/activity`. This would help you to have cleaner code and using context in `fragment/activity` is much easier. Try to define the interface between your adapter and fragment and call your interface method in the adapter and implement the interface in `activity/fragment`. There you can access context easily.

Answer (score 0):

get the activity or fragment as argument in your adapter.

```
class ArticleAdapter(private val articleActivity: ArticleActivity, private val docs: List<ArticleResult.ArticleDoc>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleAdapter.Holder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): Holder = Holder(LayoutInflater.from(p0.context).inflate(R.layout.row_general2, p0, false))
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = docs.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
        articleActivity.supportFragmentManager
    }

    class Holder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val textViewTitleRow = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewTitleRow)!!
        val textView1Row = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView1Row)!!
        val textView2Row = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2Row)!!
        val imageViewDownloadRow = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageViewDownloadRow)!!
        val textViewMoreRow = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewMoreRow)!!
        val imageViewBookRow = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageViewBookRow)!!
    }
}
```